# present with me a "ic" for only produce dead time for IGBT gate driver

Tags: driver, switching, igbt, deadly

i need to "ic" only for produce dead time with been 2 pulses.
i need dead time=={4-5 micro second}

[image]

Comment: Here is a link to the manual where the images came from, https://www.fujielectric.com/products/semiconductor/model/igbt/application/box/doc/pdf/RH983a/REH983a.pdf

Comment: I havn't seen IPM without internal dead time protection for long time, if ever. Why do you need IC?

Comment: Buy a driver with dead time setting, or make it on MCU.

Comment: Thank
Micro must be synchronous. Is problematic

Comment: Thank
Is it dead time to follow in the IPM?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need something like this: -

[image]

If you invert the OR gate output (use a NOR gate) you will get dead time between the two outputs i.e. when one goes low there is a time delay before the other goes high. The time delay is set by the R and C connected to the input called PWM.

It's probably best that you use schmitt trigger input devices too.

Comment: Thank
Do not reliable L and R?

Comment: I don't understand your question @Damirof

Comment: Is it possible to create precise dead-time with R and L?

Comment: I still don't understand your question.

Comment: is it possible to create precise dead-time with R and C?

Comment: It'll be reasonably predictable if you use Schmitt trigger gates but accuracy is less important than ensuring shoot through doesn't happen.